# Nhibernate many to many with property

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, nhibernate, many-to-many

Hey i need help with a many to many relation in NHibernate i am getting this error :

```
NHibernate.MappingException: Unable to build the insert statement for class SelfHost.Core.Repository.implementation.HibernateProduktHaendler: a failure occured when adding the Id of the class ---> System.ArgumentException: The column 'Produkt_P_ID' has already been added in this SQL builder (Parameter 'columnName')
```

i have 3 tables produkt, Haendler and ProduktHaendler , the ProduktHaendler has Haendler_H_ID as a prime and foreign key at the same time and Produkt_P_ID as a prime and foreign key at the same time (i think this is the problem)

this is my class Prdoukthaendler and the mapping

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SelfHost.Core.Repository.implementation
{
  public  class HibernateProduktHaendler
    {
        public virtual HibernateProdukt Produkt_P_ID { set;get; }

        public virtual string ProduktURL { set; get; }
        public virtual HibernateHaendler Haendler_H_ID { set; get; }


       

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            HibernateProduktHaendler id;
            id = (HibernateProduktHaendler)obj;
            if (id == null)
                return false;
            if (Produkt_P_ID == id.Produkt_P_ID && Haendler_H_ID == id.Haendler_H_ID)
                return true;
            return false;
        }


        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Produkt_P_ID + "|" +Haendler_H_ID).GetHashCode();
        }

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="SelfHost"
                   namespace="SelfHost.Core.Repository.implementation">

    <class name="HibernateProduktHaendler" table="ProduktHaendler">
        

        <id  class="HibernateProduktHaendler">
            <key-property name="Produkt_P_ID"   type="int"></key-property>
            <key-property name="Haendler_H_ID"  type="int"></key-property>
        
    
    
        </id>

        <property name="ProduktURL" />

        <many-to-one  name="Produkt_P_ID"  ></many-to-one>

        <many-to-one  name="Haendler_H_ID" ></many-to-one>
            
        

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the [composite-id](https://nhibernate.info/blog/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.html) mapping. You don't need the other many-to-one mappings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="SelfHost"
               namespace="SelfHost.Core.Repository.implementation">

<class name="HibernateProduktHaendler" table="ProduktHaendler">
    
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="Produkt_P_ID" />
        <key-many-to-one name="Haendler_H_ID" />       
    </composite-id>

    <property name="ProduktURL" />

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```